# How to use single quotes inside single quots to run bash script from ruby controller

Tags: ruby, bash

Hi Guys I am trying to read a zipped folder using bash commands. I am totally new to it. I am unable to use double quots inside double quots which leads to an error while executing this command.

```
captured_content = capture_stdout do
      system("tar -tf 3531622.tar.xz | awk -F'/' '{ for (i=1;i<4;i++) print "/"$i ; print "\n"}' ORS='' |grep "/"|uniq")
    end
```

Any help would be appreciated and please dont downvote the question I reaaly need help in it.

Comment: did you try a heredoc?

Comment: `%Q()` for interpolated string, `%q()` otherwise. Or heredoc.

Comment: @max sorry I am not familiar with that :(

Comment: You are not familiar with what? Doing your homework yourself? Googling? Reading the documentation instead of just broadcasting silly question and ignore answers?

Comment: @mudasobwa dont get hyper man! I didnt ignore your answer instead I used it and it is working great!!! Thanks a lot for saving my time :)

Comment: I am not ablt to give two votes here lolzz. 20 votes for you @mudasobwa ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the backtick operator to delimit a command - it will return the result of the command. For example:

```
output = `ls /usr/`
=> "X11\nX11R6\nadic\nbin\nlib\n"
puts output
X11
X11R6
adic
bin
lib
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use shellwords

```
require "shellwords"
args = ["ls", "/usr/"]
output = `#{args.shelljoin}`
```

this handles quotes and everything for you